# jQuery Validation 1.10 and MVC server-side errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

This feature used to work just fine on my website.

If I added a custom error to ModelState, the input on the page would be marked as "input-validation-error" and the Html.ValidationMessage() would take care of rendering a span with the error message inside it.

Due to incompatibility reasons we had to upgrade our jQuery Validation to 1.10:

Now when I add a custom error to ModelState, I can debug and see that the HTML elements being rendered correctly, but as soon as the page load is completed, jQuery Validation **removes the error message** and set the **"class" attribute of the input to "valid"**!

Has any one else come across this issue?

**UPDATE**

Testing further shows that the error message is shown on the screen until the field gains focus. As soon as the field gains focus jQuery Validation removes the customer server-side error message and marks the field as good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing further shows that the error message is shown on the screen until the field gains focus. As soon as the field gains focus jQuery Validation removes the customer server-side error message and marks the field as good.

So as long as you ensure the field does not get focus when the page loads, user still have a chance to see the error messages.

I am not sure if there is a better solution out there for MVC custom validation errors.